# I am facing the error on App Store Connect - Flight test, Individual testers status No Builds Available

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

Individual testers that I add with their email address are not receiving any email and in the console I see that No build is available.

I don't know what's going on, I released another build and this time Accepted Encryption Export Regulation as Standard, then for like 2 hours I could add Users but now suddenly It says no builds available and old emails are also removed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I released 2 builds, so the previous build is now reviewed by apple and available for testing, Now I am able to add the Testers Email, but for the current Build I can't and it says No build is available, so maybe you need to wait before apple reviews your build.